# Insertar arreglo de datos a una tabla en MySQL utilizando PHP

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto web y necesito insertar datos en dos tablas diferentes: `cascos` y `ordentrabajodetalle`, ambas tablas están relacionadas y la manera en como quiero insertar los datos es la siguiente:

Mediante Ajax y en el controlador, he acomodado el código para que se mande un arreglo de datos en caso de que el usuario desee ingresar más de un casco, cuando se ingresan nuevos cascos, se crea también un registro en la tabla "ordentrabajodetalle" al mismo tiempo.

Aquí el código:

```
  function insertar($ordenFolio, $ordenId, $cascos)
    {
        global $conexion;

        // Consulta SQL para insertar un casco (con múltiples valores específicos)
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cascos (ordenFolio, idOrden, idMarca, idMedida, modelo, idTipo, DOT, renovada, cantRenovadas, garantia, aptoRenovado) VALUES ";

        $tipos = "";
        $valores = [];
        $idCascosInsertados = []; // Arreglo para almacenar los idCasco insertados

        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);

        if ($stmt) {
            foreach ($cascos as $i => $casco) {
                if ($i > 0) {
                    $sql .= ", ";
                }
                $sql .= "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

                // Verificamos que los índices existan antes de agregarlos al arreglo $valores
                $valores[] = $ordenFolio;
                $valores[] = $ordenId;
                $valores[] = isset($casco['idMarca']) ? $casco['idMarca'] : null;
                $valores[] = isset($casco['idMedida']) ? $casco['idMedida'] : null;
                $valores[] = isset($casco['modelo']) ? $casco['modelo'] : null;
                $valores[] = isset($casco['idTipo']) ? $casco['idTipo'] : null;
                $valores[] = isset($casco['DOT']) ? $casco['DOT'] : null;
                $valores[] = isset($casco['renovada']) ? $casco['renovada'] : null;
                $valores[] = isset($casco['cantRenovadas']) ? $casco['cantRenovadas'] : null;
                $valores[] = isset($casco['garantia']) ? $casco['garantia'] : null;
                $valores[] = isset($casco['aptoRenovado']) ? $casco['aptoRenovado'] : null;

                // Construimos la cadena de tipos con la cantidad correcta de caracteres "s" e "i"
                $tipos .= "siiisississ";

                $stmt->bind_param($tipos, ...$valores);
                $result = $stmt->execute();

                if ($result) {
                    // Obtener el idCasco insertado
                    $idCascoInsertado = $stmt->insert_id;
                    $idCascosInsertados[] = $idCascoInsertado;
                } else {
                    // Si hay un error en la inserción, puedes manejarlo según tu lógica
                }

                // Restablecer los valores y tipos para la próxima iteración
                $valores = [];
                $tipos = "";
            }

            $stmt->close();

            // Insertar los idCasco en la tabla "ordentrabajodetalle"
            insertarRegistroOtDetalle($idCascosInsertados, $conexion);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Función que debe crear un registro al mismo tiempo que se inserte un nuevo casco:

```
 function insertarRegistroOtDetalle($idCascos, $conexion)
    {
        $sqlOtDetalle = "INSERT INTO ordentrabajodetalle (idCasco) VALUES (?)";
        $stmtOtDetalle = $conexion->prepare($sqlOtDetalle);
        foreach ($idCascos as $idCasco) {
            $stmtOtDetalle->bind_param("i", $idCasco);
            $stmtOtDetalle->execute();
        }

        $stmtOtDetalle->close();
    }
```

Actualmente me dice que tengo un error de sintaxis:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught
mysqli_sql_exception: You have an
error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your
MariaDB server version for the right
syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

He intentado hacerlo de diferentes maneras y en una logré hacerlo sin problemas pero no obtengo el resultado deseado.

Gracias por sus aportes!

Comment: Tu error es que sigues agregando cosas a la consulta preparada dentro del bucle. Intenta declararla completa desde el inicio: **`$sql = "INSERT INTO cascos (ordenFolio, idOrden, idMarca, idMedida, modelo, idTipo, DOT, renovada, cantRenovadas, garantia, aptoRenovado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";`**. Por supuesto, quita esto: `if ($i > 0) { $sql .= ", ";}` y también esto: `$sql .= "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";` Y es que no tiene ningún sentido hacer eso cada vez. Las consultas se preparan una sola vez.

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, igual muchas gracias por responder. Al principio lo coloqué como mencionas en tu solución, pero al hacerlo así me arrojaba un error de sintaxis ya que el bucle está iterando sobre el arreglo de los cascos, entonces los values no coincidían y tuve que encontrar otra manera de hacer la consulta